# Some styles of Nativewind are not working on native (Android) but they do in the web

Tags: css, node.js, react-native, expo, tailwind-css

I am using [Tailwind (Nativewind) with Solito](https://solito.dev/tailwind) (expo React Native).
I do have a styled component with some children.
The style is properly applied on the web, but in the native version only some are applied. The gap and text-center are not working, but the background color is.

The code is something like this:

```
<Custom className="gap-5 bg-orange-100 text-center">
    <StyledText>TEST</StyledText>
    <StyledTitleBig>Login Screen</StyledTitleBig>
    <...>
</Custom>
```

This is how the native version (android) looks:

[image]

This is how the web looks (this is the objective):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/marklawlor/nativewind/issues/364) and there I got the answer that **it is the expected behavior**…

[React Native “doesn't accept CSS inheritance”](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#limited-style-inheritance), so the only way of making it work is to add the “text-center” className for each of the text components.